# How to fix Kali Linux 2020.1 hash sum mismatch error?

Tags: kali-linux, hashsum

I just recently download Kali Linux .ova from [here](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/#1572305786534-030ce714-cc3b)

When I run `sudo apt update` , it returns

```
Get:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,958 B]
Get:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [177 kB]
Get:3 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Get:4 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages [16.5 MB]
Err:4 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                                    
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:16481917 [weak]
   - SHA256:e8104c6e141812dc6112dfe9d0c29a37c78fd966aaab11ab62dc805b739ef477
   - SHA1:f719fb7dce0d1c7dcfe4bf23425ff0a0c0765093 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:5670a40723666e7553acbc5f3413aae2 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:e8104c6e141812dc6112dfe9d0c29a37c78fd966aaab11ab62dc805b739ef477
   - SHA1:61b82f2d260b2264a577a73f24c8acfce688c534 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:5670a40723666e7553acbc5f3413aae2 [weak]
   - Filesize:16481917 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 06 May 2020 06:12:17 +0000
  Release file created at: Wed, 06 May 2020 06:13:11 +0000
Get:5 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages [195 kB]                                                                                                                                                       
Get:6 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages [97.6 kB]                                                                                                                                                       
Fetched 17.0 MB in 13s (1,327 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:16481917 [weak]
    - SHA256:e8104c6e141812dc6112dfe9d0c29a37c78fd966aaab11ab62dc805b739ef477
    - SHA1:f719fb7dce0d1c7dcfe4bf23425ff0a0c0765093 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:5670a40723666e7553acbc5f3413aae2 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:e8104c6e141812dc6112dfe9d0c29a37c78fd966aaab11ab62dc805b739ef477
    - SHA1:61b82f2d260b2264a577a73f24c8acfce688c534 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:5670a40723666e7553acbc5f3413aae2 [weak]
    - Filesize:16481917 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 06 May 2020 06:12:17 +0000
   Release file created at: Wed, 06 May 2020 06:13:11 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have already done `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists`  and `sudo apt clean`. I have also changed the mirror. But nothing happens.

I use VirtualBox version 6.1.6 with Windows 10 2004 (19041.208).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Apart from the actual problem, and since you just installed the system fresh, please ensure that Kali Linux [is really what you want](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/377345). If you are a security testing expert, of course, please ignore my comment as it doesn't apply to you then (but unfortunately there are many Kali-related questions by novices who misguidedly try this distribution).

Comment: This looks like the apt repo metadata is wrong (SHA1 checksum is wrong). It is an issue on the server side. Try again after sometime. Otherwise, you can try changing the mirror kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw to some other mirror.

Comment: I had the same issue. Check out [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241893/594870), he solves it. Particularly for Windows 10 host using Virtualbox, so I'm guessing that's the issue here. For me when I asked that question, some packages worked fine but others did not. The key is [disabling Hyper-V and getting rid of that Green Turtle](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90853&sid=dd153bd7f58ac95966ee195414bdf7a5&start=270#p476261)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo bash
# mkdir /etc/gcrypt
# echo all > /etc/gcrypt/hwf.deny
```

Do these comands and then update again.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to edit your post to include an explanation _why_ this solves the OPs problem.

Comment: This answer already posted on askubuntu please add the link: https://askubuntu.com/a/1242739/498780

Comment: Actually, the same commands appear [here](https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/other/unable-to-apt-update), [here](https://github.com/ktkr3d/ktkr3d.github.io/issues/1), [here](https://memotut.com/hash-sum-mismatch-due-to-gcrypto20-38825/), [here](https://t.codebug.vip/questions-2756395.htm), [here](https://qiita.com/autumnKa15/items/3882586a62a738b53833) and [here](https://www.cyberforum.ru/debian-gnu-linux/thread2679078-page2.html) — the first one appears to predate the Ask Ubuntu answer.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks! (Kali on VB, with WSL2)